# How to get channel ids in a category on nodejs and discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How to get ID of all channels in a category in Discord.js v14 and node.js?

I tried this but I just get a error:

```js
const guild = interaction.guild; // Get guild from interaction
const category = await guild.channels.cache.get(config.ticketkategori) // get category from guild
category.channel.forEach(element => { // Simple foreach
    console.log(element.id) // Tried get channel id
});
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are facing

Answer (score 1):

```js
let categoryChannels = interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type == ChannelType.GuildText || c.type == ChannelType.GuildVoice);

categoryChannels = categoryChannels.filter((channel) => {
  if (channel.parentId === config.ticketkategori) return true;
  return false;
})
```

This snippet will get all the channels in the guild then loop/filter through them and only return the entries with the parent ID (category ID) that you want to look for.

You then have a collection that you can use to get the IDs from, like so:

```
console.log(categoryChannels[0].id)
```